# What's the difference between Lnode and LinkList?

Tags: data-structures

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}Lnode, *LinkList;
```

and when

```
LinkList p = new Lnode; 

LNode *p = new Lnode;
```

is there some difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just the redeclaration of  pointer `p` in  this line:

```
Lnode *p = new Lnode;
```

previously declared in line below

```
LinkList p = new Lnode;
```

Here writing `Lnode*` is equivalent to writing to `node*` and writing `LinkList` will also evaluate to `node*` , no difference!
Same as

```
typedef int *iptr;   // type name: iptr
                       // new type: int*

iptr ptr;            // same as: int *ptr
```

Answer (score 0):

**We use "LNode" to emphasize a "node", while using "LinkList" to emphasize a "List".Here is an example**

1. *Define a new struct*

> ```
> typedef struct {
>     int data;
>     LNode *next;
> }LNode,*LinkList;
> ```

2. *Insert a new node*

> ```
>   bool ListInsert (LinkList &L,int i,int e){
>   if (i<1)
>       return false;
>   LNode *p;
>   int j = 0;
>   p = L;
>   while (p!=NULL && j<i-2){
>       p=p->next;
>       j++;
>   }
>   if(p=NULL)
>       return false;
>  LNode * s = (LNode *)malloc(sizeofLNode));
>   s->next = p->next;
>   p->next = s;
>   return true;
> }
> ```

According to the code, we try to create a new node to insert in the original list by using "LNode *p"， while getting access to the list by tranfering parameter "LinkList &L" in the "ListInsert()" function.